# check double entries before updating database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql

This is my problem...

I have an SQL table showing flights details, like date of arrival, arrival time, departure date, departure time and so on...
Now if I want to update a flight, I want to be sure that the dates of flight are not matching with other dates, eg:

if I have a flight called IFLY arriving 10 aug departing 14 aug and same flight arriving 16 aug departing 18 aug, imagine I want to update the second flight arriving 13 aug, I should get a response like: "your flight cannot arrive before the previous one has not departed". for this I did...

```php
if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
    $regist = $_POST['reg'];
    $arrivalDate = $_POST['adof'];
    $departureDate = $_POST['ddof'];

    $sql = "SELECT reg, adof, ddof FROM flights WHERE reg = '$regist' AND  adof < $arrivalDate' order by ddof desc";//

    $data = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($data) > 0) {
        foreach ($data as $key => $v) {
            if ($v['ddof'] <= $arrivalDate) {
                echo 'exists';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but is not working because when I update is looking also for the flight that I want to update.
How to solve this, how to avoid SQL query of the current entries?

Comment: You’re going to have to query to see if there’s a conflict. If no conflict, then update. No getting around it. But you’ve got more than one problem here: 1) you need a query that accurately lets you know if you can update, 2) how to do that query and then update.  Solve in that order. In the meantime, your code could be greatly improved by using field names that are obvious in meaning, ie ‘arrival’, ‘departure’, and (I have no idea what reg means).  You’re also wide open to sql injection: before going any further, figure out how to use prepared statements and always use them.

Comment: Add a condition to your SQL to ignore first record or sort your data by date and ignore first returned record.

Answer (score -1):

What you describe is a business logic precondition requirement.  Before you execute any updates, you need to fetch the record, and evaluate if the changes would cause an absurd condition.  If so, you can reject the change with an error and not issue the update.

Comment: thank you but how to do It? that's the reason of my question

Comment: You fetch the record you intend to update. Then you evaluate the business rule.  There's nothing wrong with looking at the record you intend to update in a future step.  In fact, this is a common, and required step in most of business logic processing.  Now, if you said you wanted to do it on the SQL server side so as not to trust the client is doing the correct logic checks, you need to add an SQL UPDATE trigger, for which there are many good tutorials.

Comment: ok understood, but how to avoid sql query of the current entrie. I want to do a SELECT but not of the current entrie, is this possible?

Comment: Sure. Just change the parameters to your selections by changing how the `$sql` variable is built.  You may have to run a series of `select` queries (or, a big join) to locate the record that needs to be evaluated.  This would be pretty typical.  You're the programmer; you're always in charge of what the computer does with the data in context -- you just might have to take 2-3 or more steps to get the answer you're really looking for.

Answer (score -2):

To determine if there is an overlap in the flights, I believe you just need to see if either the new departure date is between the old departure and arrival dates, *OR* if the new arrival date is between the two old dates, *OR* if the new departure is before the old departure *and* the new arrival is after the old arrival. I think that covers all your scenarios. The query for that would be something like:

```
    SELECT TOP 1 reg, adof, ddof FROM flights 
       WHERE reg = '$regist' AND (
       (adof > $departureDate AND adof < $arrivalDate) 
       OR (ddof > $departureDate AND ddof < $arrivalDate) 
       OR (ddof < $departureDate AND adof > $arrivalDate)
       )
```

I didn't try this, but I think that's kind of what you want. The `SELECT TOP 1` should speed up the query since all you care about is if there's one record that causes the conflict. At that point, there's no reason to look for more records.